# Connecting Mongodb Atlas on Zapier

Tags: mongodb, zapier

I'm trying to connect my Mongodb Atlas database on Zapier to be able to interact with other services.

In the MongoDB Atlas interface, I copy the URI connection string :
[image: MongoDB Atlas URI connection string]

And I set it in Zapier
[image: Zapier integration]

I've made several trial. Without *"mongodb://"*, with login and password in in "Username" and "Password" fields, etc ..
But I never found the correct way to connect my database.

Example of error message I get : [image: Error Message]

Does anyone as a solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried using one only one of the URIs instead of a list of them? That could be related.

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work with only one URI ...

Comment: in that case, I'd write into contact@zapier.com and have our support team help you out!

Comment: Having an issue connecting as well, using just the hostname of my current primary. The first steps succeed but then can not go further. Will keep trying.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Need support

Comment: I am also struggling with this one. Potentially @prasad from below can share his solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from Zapier about this issue:

*"
I appreciate you sending me that information.*

*I took a look and it seems that the MongoDB does not have a stable release for version 3.xxx and higher. From my notes here, the last stable release we had was for MongoDB version 2.4.4. [...] The good news is you're not the first user to report this problem and it's on our radar.*

*[...] I don’t have an ETA of when or if this will happen, but we will definitely email you when this is fixed! Keep an eye out for our Zapier Updates in your inbox.*

*A limited number of users were able to get this working by temporarily adding 0.0.0.0/0 to the IP Whitelist in atlas. You can find out how to do this here: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/. You can definitely give this a try but we found that this does not work for most users."*

The above suggested whitelisting of 0.0.0.0/0 did not work for me, since I already had that...

-> **I will let you guys know once there is a solution provided my Zapier/MongoDB to this issue if they email me. Idk when that is...**

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of troubleshooting, I was able to get this to work using the settings below. You kind of have to think about those fields as a URL builder and split things up between the fields. My host is just the basic hostname of one shard, without mongodb://

[image: Screenshot of Setup]

Comment: This does not work for me: when I try to create a zap, i get the error `database names cannot contain the character '/'`

Comment: This is a valid answer. I faced the same issue, and talked with mongoDB support. This was the provided answer. As the screenshot above, remove the / at the beginning of the databse field and replace it with your database name. You should have something like `myFirstDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=DB-production-shard-0&authSource=admin&w=majority`. Also be sure to make your mongoDB cluster available from everywhere (adding `0.0.0.0/0` to the `whitelist addresses`). This will work. You also need to get your `sharded address` from mongoDB. (regular protocol, not SRV)

Answer (score 0):

The OP has entered (as per their image) host name **with** the port number, database name, username and password already. As per the Zapier guidelines shown on the image itself,  host name should be entered without database used, port number, username and password. Then port number should be entered followed by database used, username and password. Zapier threw an error because port number `27017` got mixed with the other entries (database name, port number, username and password) and port number was no longer perceived as integer. **If entries are made properly and separately without mixing them, adding the MongoDB cloud account works**. Maybe this helps OP and someone else facing the same issue.

Comment: Could you share your solution with a screenshot please? I‘m unable to get it work and also tried already all kinds of variations like OP. I am struggling to get the host right I think. The remaining fields should be pretty straightforward.